# Which to use Ate or eat in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Do i say, “why do you have to eat after I eat/ate?”. Im confuse because I ate and they havent.

Comment: They are both correct, depending on the context.

Comment: Notice how "to eat" is an infinite and present verb, meaning it's an action in that is about to happen. So, "why do you have to eat after I ate?" If you wanted to use "eat" use its past participle "eaten"; "Why do you have to eat after I have eaten?" (as the 'after' suggests its an action that just happened so I used the present perfect "have" eaten.)

Comment: If it was "why do you have to eat when I eat?" would be correct if you used it in this context.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do you have to eat after I ate?

I have just eaten, and you are now eating, why do you have to do that?

> Why do you have to eat after I eat?

You often eat after I eat, why do you have to do that?

In the first sentence the *ate* is past tense referring to what has just happened and the "have to eat" is present tense (combining the present tense *have* and the infinitive *to eat*) referring to what is happening now.

In the second the *eat* is habitual present referring to things that tend to happen, and the present tense of "have to eat" is also in a habitual way.

The habitual may not even mean that it has indeed happened before, so much as it is an approach to things that someone is taken, even if it was the only time it happened. It does though imply that it could happen again; that your question is placed outside of a particular incident even if it actually does relate to one.

> Im confuse because I ate and they havent.

Are you perhaps thinking that one shouldn't mix tenses? That's often advice given, but it's an oversimplification. Really one shouldn't be afraid to mix tenses when appropriate, with each verb in whatever tense it is in for a good reason. The bad mixing of tenses is if you e.g. move from past tense to present because you've mentally lost track of just what tense you are expressing (which even experienced native speakers can do as a slip if they lose their train of thought mid-composition).

Comment: "Why do you have to eat after I eat?" doesnt make sense due to the preposition 'after'.

Comment: @1006a, I didn't say "ate".

Comment: @aesking Sorry, I meant "eat" is fine if you are talking about something that always or regularly happens. Just like you can say "After one thing happens, another thing happens." So "Every time, first I eat; then after I eat, you eat. What's up with that?"

Comment: @1600a wouldnt it be better to say "why do you have to eat when I eat?" Im not saying you cant use eat if it reguarly happens but if you're using the preposition 'after'..im not sure.

Comment: It depends on the situation; there's no grammatical reason not to say it. If Person A always waits to eat until *after* Person B has finished their meal, then the OP's question makes perfect sense with "eat".@aesking

Comment: @aesking it would not be better to say "why do you have to eat when I eat?" because that means something different. *When* means at the same time, *after* means at a later time.

Comment: No if person A always wait to eat until after person B then it is "why do you (person A) have to eat after I [have] ate/eaten (person B)?" Not "not why do you (person A) have to eat after I [have] eat (person b)". In the latter there is no distinction and if person B has just finished eating you would use 'have' and 'have eat' doesn't make sense; or you could use ate: "After I have ate". @1006a

Comment: After doesn't necessarily mean at a later time just that in this context that person B is preceded by person A. Does that make sense? By using "why do you have to eat after I eat" suggests that they both happen at the same time, so it would be more correct to use 'when'; but thats not the context the OP stated. @Jon Hanna

Comment: @aesking you certainly could use the past perfect "after I have eaten". "Have eat" is not grammatical in Standard English but is in some dialects (and was in Early Modern) where *eat* can be a past participle. Also, the OP didn't give any context. I'm not at all getting what definition of *after* you are using here.